# Having trouble using SDL framework on XCode

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, sdl, libraries

I am having trouble using the SDL framework in my xcode project, my main (all there is in the project at the moment) currently looks like this:

```
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
// insert code here...
std::cout << "Hello, World!\n";
return 0;
}
```

And the error I am receiving when building is:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>     "_main", referenced from:
>         start in crt1.10.6.o
>        (maybe you meant: __Z8SDL_mainiPPKc)
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

It does not give me an error about the framework not being found. and I have looked around Stackoverflow for this problem and I did find one person who had their framework in the wrong place on their OS. But I have tried all places (/library/frameworks &&  /~username~/library/frameworks && /system/library/frameworks) and still no luck.

Additional info:
I did however notice after some searching on the internet that the official website http://www.libsdl.org/download-1.2.php
Does not have a OSX version of the Development library. While many tutorials on how to use SDL on OSX say these are required.

Also I am adding my library via Xcode itself ,not through drag'ndrop. Xcode seems to reckognize it.

Would be much appreciated if anyone could help, going crazy over this error.

UPDATE:

[image: error]

Still no luck, I have followed every step provided by solutions here below. perhaps this screenshot is of any help.

The main() function is corrected, but didn't help. I tried changing the path to the header files, im lost on this one. Does anyone perhaps have any alternatives to building this in xcode?

UPDATE2:

The suggestion worked, however now it is giving me this warning, which won't let me run the application.

[image]

Fixed! I removed the path in the build settings. Strange how I still don't know what went wrong, either way. thanks a lot for the help! made my day!

Comment: Are you linking with `SDLmain`?

Comment: Can you run `sdl-config --libs` on your command line?

Comment: @jrok No i am not, this doesn't seem necessary for most tutorials I find online, however I have tried this and I still get the same error after I do.

Comment: @KerrekSB I tried entering it on a fresh command line and it said: command not found, Do i have to run this on the application?

Comment: @Sam: no, it's not important. It would just have given us a clue as to the location of your SDL libraries. Have you added `-lSDL` to the compiler command?

Comment: Yes it't there, no luck yet :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see three possible problems. The first problem is how you're including SDL.h in your code. You should include SDL.h with the following code:

```
#include "SDL.h"
```

The second possible problem is you haven't added the files SDLMain.h and SDLMain.m to your project. Those files are necessary to compile SDL code on Mac OS X. The files are in the devel-lite folder on the SDL disk image.

The third possible problem is that your project doesn't link to the Cocoa framework. The Mac version of SDL uses Cocoa so you need the Cocoa framework in your project.

The following article walks you through the setup of an Xcode 4 project for SDL:

[Using SDL with Xcode 4](http://meandmark.com/blog/2012/01/using-sdl-with-xcode-4/)

UPDATE

I noticed a possible problem in how you defined the main() function. You have a space between char and * and another space between * and argv, which could be causing the error. The main() function in my SDL code is defined in the following way:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however this is the tutorial I followed to include SDL into my project (one of many). and it gives me the same error :( 

also The include part gives me an error that it cannot find SDL, no error on "SDL/sdl.h". I feel like it isn't an error with including the framework. although I could be mistaken

Comment: Make sure the SDL framework is part of the target's Link Binary with Libraries build phase. You may also need to add the path to the SDL framework to the Framework Search Paths build setting.

Comment: It is linked and also the paths give no errors. I posted a screenshot of the error, perhaps it can show you a bit more about it.

Comment: The error message says you have a duplicate symbol main. This means Xcode has found two main() functions in your project when you can only have one. Search your project for main and see what comes up.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! If I search my project for "main" it only shows up once, the weird part is, if I add or remove this line "#import "sdl/sdl.h" it works or doesn't work. Could another main be in the SDL kit? seems strange cause if i remove the only main there is in my project the app still won't build.

Comment: SDLMain.m also has a main() function, but don't delete it. SDL is very picky on how you define main() in your program, which I've mentioned in this answer and in the article I linked to. If you go to my site, which I linked to in the article, you can find my SDL OpenGL article that includes an Xcode 4 project. It might help you find what the problem is on your end.

Comment: Thanks tons, this is finally building, however it does give one final warning which won't let me run the application, check my updated post.

Comment: I think it's probably const char* vs char*, rather than the space, that's doing it.